# Smokeping list only systems down

Tags: monitoring

I'm using [smokeping](http://oss.oetiker.ch/smokeping/) to monitor our 400+-systems.
Everything works and functions as it should.

Only i want to make a view or a filter that only shows the lines that are down, or that match a certain pattern, as in the alerts-section.

Can anybody help me with the configuration of such a listing-page in smokeping?
Or can anybody point me in the right direction?